# Highcharts Multiple Series data - label mismatch

Tags: charts, highcharts, bar-chart

I have multiple series lets call them

```
A, B, C, D
```

I have pulled the series data like so

```
data:[1,2,3], data:[4,5,6], data[3,5,7], data[7,8,9]
```

The data is showing correctly on the bar chart
But when I click the series name/identifier on the y-Axis while the bar shows the correct data, the label that appears beside the bar, is incorrect.It seems to use an index based correlation between series and labels

Here is my code:

```
axios.get('/api/getData')
          .then((response) => {
            let data= response.data

        //initialize series, category arrays
        let series = [];
        let categories = [];

        //group data by product types
        let productTypeGroups = _.groupBy(stockData, (product) => {
            return product.type;
        });

        //loop through grouped data and create series for each product type
        for(const[key,value] of Object.entries(productTypeGroups)){

          let dataValues= _.map(value, (product)=>{

              //push product names into category array
              categories.push(product.name)

              return product.current_balance < 0 ? 0 : product.current_balance;
          })

          //set default visibility to true if product is vaccine
          let visibility = key === 'A' ? true : false

          series.push({
            name:key,
            data:dataValues,
            visible:visibility
          })
        }

        this.dataValuesChart.highchartOptions.xAxis.categories = categories
        this.dataValuesChart.dataValues.series = series
```

Here is the HighCharts Config:

```
   highchartOptions: {
      chart: {
        type: 'bar',
        height: 500
      },
      title: {
        text: 'Stock Balance'
      },
      subtitle: {
        text: ''
      },
      yAxis: {
        title: {
          text: 'Doses'
        },
        labels: {
          format: '{value}'
        }
      },
      xAxis: {
        categories: [],
        labels:{
          step:1
        }
      },
      plotOptions: {
        series: {
          label: {
            connectorAllowed: false
          }
        }
      },
      series: [],
      responsive: {
        rules: [{
          condition: {
            maxWidth: 500
          },
          chartOptions: {
            legend: {
              layout: 'horizontal',
              align: 'center',
              verticalAlign: 'bottom'
            }
          }
        }]
      }
    }
```

Here is a screenshot of how the chart displays:
[image]

How does the click event know what labels to pull, should we use some sort of dynamic category setting for this to work? Is there another way to do this even?

Comment: Hi @watkib, Could you recreate the problem in jsfiddle? As you can see in this simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/g2v9cj7b/ everything works as expected.

Comment: @ppotaczek Firstly, thank you for the jsfiddle. We can use your example on there:

Comment: @ppotaczek see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jdm8rh1s/ : I would like when I click on Continents, only bars for Asia and Africa show, when I click on Cars only bars for Honda and Toyota show. How can i possibly achieve this

Comment: Thanks for the simple description of the problem. Please check this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/p6jahkwv/ - it should fulfil your requirements.

Comment: @ppotaczek Thank you for this. It is what I am looking for. Just one thing: Please explain the new multi-dimensional structure of the data array, I would like to know how I can implement this in my actual code

Comment: You can find the best description in API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.bar.data The first value is `x` and the second is `y`.

Comment: @ppotaczek Thank you , this really helped. You solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Credit @ppoctaczek for pointing out the data array can also be a multidimensional array [x, y] as documented here: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.bar.data

In terms of hiding the unclicked series @ppoctaczek suggested I edit the plotOption section like so. NB default behaviour on click is to add or remove clicked series to already clicked series - you can retain these defaults if that works for you.

```
      plotOptions: {
        series: {
          label: {
            connectorAllowed: false
          },
          grouping:false,
          events:{
            legendItemClick: function(){
              this.chart.series.forEach(s=>{
                s.hide();
              });
              this.show();
              return false;
            }
          }
        }
      },
```

Then in terms of the data array I needed to make it multidimensional, and have the x value referencing the serial indices of the categories across the multiple series. I achieved this by:

```
        //initialize index counter
        let i = 0;

        //loop through grouped data and create series for each product type
        for(const[key,value] of Object.entries(productTypeGroups)){

            let balances = [];
          _.each(value, (product)=>{

              //push product names into category array
              categories.push(product.name)

              //push index and balance into balances array
              balances.push([i, product.current_balance]);

              //increment index
              i++;
          })

          //set default visibility to true if product is vaccine
          let visibility = key === 'vaccine' ? true : false

          series.push({
            name:key,
            data:balances,
            visible:visibility
          })
        }
```

Your data array on console.log your series data should look like this:

[image]